# Sound defaults to vibrate

Tags: notifications, samsung-galaxy-nexus, audio

Sound defaults to vibrate after any notification even though phone (Nexus) is on loud.
Tried power off and battery switch. Changed vibrate and ring tone settings.

Comment: Does it still vibrate even if you turn off vibration?

Comment: Could you add more info, such as if this happens even when you or in normal mode or if the phone switches to silent mode automatically?